# Understanding the sentence あなたの学校に何がありますか

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

As the title says, I'm looking for some help understanding the following sentence:

> あなたの学校に何がありますか。

I'm really confused with this sentence, especially about the use of 何 here. Could someone help me translate / understand it better?

As far as I can tell, a direct translation would be:

> your school what there is?

Which makes no sense.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Please try to avoid writing answers in the comments section.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14274/9831

Answer (score 1):

You're not too far off. The に acts as 'at'.

Your school / at / what / there is / ?
As it it a question, the 'is' will come before 'there'.

```
何がありますか？ What is there.

野球場｛やきゅうじょう｝があります。There is a baseball field.
```

As far as what the person asking really wants to know, it is unclear from the context. One can assume, however, that they know what is normally provided at a school, so they are likely asking 'What is there (that is special) at your school.'

Just to summarize, the translation to the phrase is:

> 'What is there at your school?'

Answer (score 1):

To translate something, you have to not only get the word-by-word meanings right, you have to understand the difference in sentence structures and make sure to move the words around correctly.

When trying to understand a sentence in Japanese, always start with the final verb and build on that. In this case, the verb is あります - "[there] is".

Building on that, the two main things are the subject - 何 - and the fact that it's a question, thanks to the sentence-end particle か. So adding those in, you get "What is [there]?".

Then we add the "fluff" - the additional information marked with particles like に, any relative clauses, and other stuff that adds detail to the main sentence. In this case, we have あなたの学校に - "at your school".

So our final sentence is "What is there at your school?", which depending on context might just become "What does your school have?" or something similar.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't considering the fact that が is used as the topic marker here. This helps a lot, thanks!